# Cannot append in IE, works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I think IE hates me. Everything I do in other browsers works, but IE 11, no! It is failing. I'm guessing it's me and not the browser.

I have a `<select>` list on my web page, and I'm trying to bind the `<option>` dynamically.

So far, it works great in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. There is no error in the IE Development tools (F12) so I'm lost as to why it refuses to work.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u311uzg9/3/)**

HTML

```
<select id="MyList">
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    var myItems=[];
    myItems.push({"All":"Hello"});
    myItems.push({"One":"And More"});
    myItems.push({"Two":"Lots More"});   

    for (i = 0; i< myItems.length;i++)  {
        for (item in myItems[i]) {
            var x = myItems[i][item]; //for my testing
            var y = myItems[item];    //for my testing
            $("#MyList").append("<option>" + item + "</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

If you try the fiddle in FF or Chrome, all good. The `select` list populates with All, One and Two.

Short of a gift or even some form of sacrifice to the IE elves, what do I need to do to make IE happy with me?

Comment: *I think IE hates me* - Nope, `IE` hates Internet and its Development! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bizarre. When I run that fiddle in the IE I have handy (IE9), I get an "access denied" error and jQuery isn't loaded. If I change the fiddle to use 1.11.0 rather than 1.10.1, I don't get that error and the script runs.

There are a couple of issues with the code, primarily undeclared variables (your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)); here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u311uzg9/6/) with:

- Variable declarations
- Using jQuery 1.11.0
- Using the "no wrap - body" option rather than "onload", since you're using the ready event

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var myItems=[];
    myItems.push({"All":"Hello"});
    myItems.push({"One":"And More"});
    myItems.push({"Two":"Lots More"});

    var i, item;
    for (i = 0; i< myItems.length;i++)  {
        for (item in myItems[i]) {
            var x = myItems[i][item];
            var y = myItems[item];
            $("#MyList").append("<option>" + item + "</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

Separately, though, to be compatible with a wider range of browsers, you might want to use the `Option` constructor and the `add` method of the `options` list rather than appending a DOM element; some older browsers prefer it. That looks like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u311uzg9/11/)

```
// Before the loop...
var options = $("#MyList")[0].options;

// ...in the loop
options.add(new Option(item));
```

Comment: +1 : always a fan of your lucid and elaborate explanation! :)

Comment: Odd, it actually ONLY fails on jQuery 1.10.1... I've just tried it with JQuery 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1 and 1.11.0 - Now to see what else will break on my site by moving from 1.10.1 to 1.11.1 - Thank you

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: I'm guessing some issue with the CDN jsFiddle uses (code.jquery.com), but I can't think of one that would only affect IE! :-) I'd migrate to 1.11.1. I don't think the changes from 1.9.1 to 1.11.1 are particularly "breaking."

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u311uzg9/13/)

```
var sel = $("#MyList");
sel.empty();                
for (var i = 0; i< myItems.length;i++)  {
    for (var item in myItems[i]) {
        var x = myItems[i][item];
        var y = item;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);            
        sel.append('<option value="' + x + '">' + y + '</option>');
    }
}
```

As already mentioned by @ T.J.Crowder in IE 10 jquery1.10.1 is not working and updating the jquery version to later it started to work;

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    var myItems=[];
    myItems.push({"All":"Hello"});
    myItems.push({"One":"And More"});
    myItems.push({"Two":"Lots More"});


    for (i = 0; i< myItems.length;i++)  {
        for (item in myItems[i]) {
            var x = myItems[i][item];
            $('#MyList')
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value",x)
             .text(item)); 
        }
    }
});
```